# Replacing xml tags in BASH

Tags: bash, sed

I have a large collection of xml documents with a wide array of different tags in them. I need to change all tags of the form `<foo>` and turn them into tags of the form `<field name="foo">` in a way that will also ignore the attributes of a given tag. That is, a tag of the form `<foo id="bar">` should also be changed to the tag `<field name="foo">`.

In order for this transformation to work, I also need to distinguish between `<foo>` and `</foo>`, as `</foo>` must go to `</field>`.

I have played around with sed in a bash script, but to no avail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/900873

Comment: Give more concrete examples of the required transformations.

Comment: For instance, `<html>` would go to `<field name="html">`, `<person>` would go to `<field name="person">`, but `<person name="bob">` and `<person name="tom">` would both become `<field name="person">`; you would lose the name component.

Comment: how about tags with attributes. would the attributes be discarded? (add all this to your question, not as comments)

Comment: Choose a language with a proper XML parser; don't try to treat XML as regular text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although sed is not ideal for this task (see comments; further reading: regular, context-free grammar and xml), it can be pressed into service. Try this one-liner:

```
sed -e 's/<\([^>\/\ ]*\)[^>]*>/<field name=\"\1\">/g' -e 's/<field name=\"\">/<\/field>/g' file
```

First it will replace all end tags with `</field>`, then replace every open tag first words with `<field name="firstStoredWord">`

This solution prints everything on the standard output. If you want to replace it in file directly when processing, try

```
sed -i -e 's/<\([^>\/\ ]*\)[^>]*>/<field name=\"\1\">/g' -e 's/<field name=\"\">/<\/field>/g' file
```

That makes from

```
<html>
<person> 
but <person name="bob"> and <person name="tom"> would both become
</person>
```

this

```
<field name="html">
<field name="person"> 
but <field name="person"> and <field name="person"> would both become
</field>
```

Comment: All of the closing tags here turned into `<field name="">`. The first sed command properly converts them into `</field>`, but the second command changes `</field>` to `<field name="">`.

Comment: `sed` is *not* in general ideal for this task. It might work if your XML is completely regular, but that it comconly not the case; and the requirement is easy to avoid by switching to a properly XML-aware tool.

Comment: Sure, I agree. But I dont know a common bash tool that can parse xml (or non-regular, context-free grammar). Sed is ideal for this task from the common bash tools provided.

Answer (score 0):

Sed is the wrong tool for the job - a simple XSL Transform can do this much more reliably:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match="foo">
      <field name="foo">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </field>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that unlike sed, it can handle short empty elements, newlines within tags (e.g. as produced by some tools), and just about anything that's well-formed XML.  Here's my test file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
  <section>
    <foo>Plain foo, simple content</foo>
  </section>
  <foo attr="0">Foo with attr, with content
    <bar/>
    <foo attr="shorttag"/>
  </foo>
  <foo
    attr="1"
  >multiline</foo
  >
  <![CDATA[We mustn't transform <foo> in here!]]>
</doc>
```

which is transformed by the above (using `xsltproc 16970175.xslt 16970175.xml`) to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
  <section>
    <field name="foo">Plain foo, simple content</field>
  </section>
  <field name="foo">Foo with attr, with content
    <bar/>
    <field name="foo"/>
  </field>
  <field name="foo">multiline</field>
  We mustn't transform &lt;foo&gt; in here!
</doc>
```